# Transition from javax to jakarta in Jakarta EE and Spring Framework 6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

The program I'm currently working on uses Java 17 and Spring Boot 2.6.4, I need to add a jQuery DataTables dependency to the `pom` file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, this dependency is not compatible with the Spring Boot `2.6.4` so I upgraded to `3.1.2` and because of this change I now have to use `jakarta` instead of `javax` and I also have to migrate from spring-security 5 to 6. Without these changes the application starts and works fine, but when I make the changes I see no error in the console, but Intellij notifies me: `Failed to retrieve application JMX service URL`

This is the `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>[redacted]</groupId>
    <artifactId>[redacted]</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>[application name]</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>[redacted]</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>mysql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>6.0.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>--> DataTables dependency

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is the main 'runner' file:

```
import com.[].[].entity.Employee;
import com.[].[].entity.UserAccount;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityCollection;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.SecurityConstraint;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
//import org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.repository.DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = DataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@EnableScheduling
public class KycApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(KycApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(KycApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        // Enable SSL Traffic
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
                SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                collection.addPattern("/*");
                securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
                context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
            }
        };

        // Add HTTP to HTTPS redirect
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(httpToHttpsRedirectConnector());

        return tomcat;
    }

    /*
    We need to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. Without SSL, this application used
    port 8082. With SSL it will use port 8443. So, any request for 8082 needs to be
    redirected to HTTPS on 8443.
     */
    private Connector httpToHttpsRedirectConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme("http");
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setRedirectPort(443);
        return connector;
    }

}
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You should detail the changes that cause the error. Furthermore in the `pom` I see Java 17 instead of 19.

Comment: The only changes I made that causes the error, is changing the version of spring to `3.1.2` spring-security from 5 to 6 and since `javax ` to `jakarta`

Comment: What about `spring-boot-starter-security`? It has a fixed and old version. Also note that the thymeleaf dependency refers to Spring 5.

Comment: The `spring-boot-starter-security` I'm not sure if it is fixed or old, I assume it's not because it is generated by https://start.spring.io/;

Comment: Both fixed and old: you have to remove it's `version` tag, and also upgrade thymeleaf (at least).

Comment: @Pino so I removed the version tag and changed thymeleaf version to 3.1.2, error still persists

Comment: You are mixing modules from a single framework, never do this. You should only have as spring boot version in your parent, the other `spring-boot-starter-*` must not have a version, nor should your `spring-boot-maven-plugin` have a version. The maven compiler plugin should go as well and you should set the `java.version` property to 17 to work with Spring Boot 3. Finally the `maven-compiler-plugin` as a dependency doesn't make any sense, remove it.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I tried this and it didn't work, the compiler stalls at `HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy`

Comment: THat isn't a compiler message that is a message from the start of the application, probably in a test.

Comment: Yeah I understand that now however, I still get the notification from IntelliJ at run-time: `Failed to retrieve application JMX service URL` I assume it could be an issue with hibernate and the @Audited annotation but I'm not sure

Comment: After about 45 minutes, I get an exception: `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Java heap space `